# Can PHP communicate with Dynamics AX business connector?

Tags: php, axapta, business-connector

PROBLEM: I need to feed data from a PHP script into Dynamics AX.

METHOD: I suppose the easiest way to do this is by using the Dynamics AX Business Connector.

QUESTION: Is it possible to connect to the Dynamics AX Business Connector directly from a PHP script? If so: How?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, I don't think that is possible.  The Business Connector is used for .NET or legacy COM applications.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to call the [Dynamics AX .NET Business Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa659581.aspx) from PHP using the [DOTNET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) class.

Comment: yes you can, or use one of the various dlls which allow php to connect to the windows API and use the COM business connector

Answer (score 0):

You can connect MS Dynamics AX 2009 from PHP 5.* Using the following examples code:

```
$Axapta = new COM("AxaptaCOMConnector.Axapta3.1") or die("Cannot start AX for you"); 
$Axapta->Logon("MMKT", "en-us", "LOCAL_AX_DEV@MMOP-IS:2714", "");

$xml_repairorder =  "<parameters>";
$xml_repairorder .= "<recId>5637318352</recId>,";
$xml_repairorder .= "</parameters>";

$return = $Axapta->CallStaticClassMethod("WebRepairOrder", "DeleteSymptom", $xml_repairorder);
```

Description

```
MMKT =  Company Name
LOCAL_AX_DEV = .axc file name
MMOP-IS = Server Name
2714 = Port AX
WebRepairOrder = Class Name on AOT
DeleteSymptom = Function Name in WebRepairOrder Class
```

Comment: I have a project where i might need to connect to AX 2009. I haven't looked much into this, but can you tell me where i would get the COM connecter "AxaptaCOMConnector.Axapta3.1" from?