# Using PHP to Update Dynamics AX 2012 Workflow

Tags: php, .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am currently attempting to set up a PHP script to communicate with Dynamics AX 2012 and update a workflow (i.e. approve and reject), and after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176325/can-php-communicate-with-dynamics-ax-business-connector) I believe it can be achieved using the business connector - however I also read a lot of articles advising not to use the Business Connector with AX 2012 and so I would like to avoid doing so *if possible*.

My question is: How can I use PHP (or any other language I can call through PHP) to communicate with AX 2012 to approve/reject or otherwise update existing workflows **without** using the business connector?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use AIF ([*Application Integration Framework*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731810.aspx)).

Then you can call AX AIF services via SOAP (Web Services). Use `HTTP` adapter instead of default `NetTcp` (or configure it to use `BasicHttp`).

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh496418.aspx for the instructions of configuring HTTP Adapter.

For workflow actions AIF service is already created ([`\Services\SysWorkflowApprovalService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sysworkflowapprovalservice.applyaction.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

The better way is Connect your PHP Application to WCF service then easily Integrate that WCF service into AIF then call AIF to Dynamics AX,
i think this best approach.